# how to insert dropdown column data into excel in c# using oledb

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I want to insert data into excel. But, excel contains dropdown columns and normal columns.
I am using oledb provider to insert the data into excel normal columns but i can't insert dropdown column values using oledb, could someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

By using Excel Interop  you can achieve the drop down list.

Below is the example code

```
        // Create an Excel object
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        //Create workbook object
        string str = @"E:\test.xlsx";
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(Filename: str);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet1 = workbook.ActiveSheet;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = worksheet1.get_Range("A1","A1");
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDowns xlDropDowns;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDown xlDropDown;
        xlDropDowns = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDowns)(workbook.ActiveSheet.DropDowns(Type.Missing)));
        xlDropDown = xlDropDowns.Add((double)range.Left, (double)range.Top, (double)range.Width, (double)range.Height, true);
        xlDropDown.AddItem("item1",1);
        xlDropDown.AddItem("item2", 2);


        //Save the workbook
        workbook.Save();

        //Close the Workbook
        workbook.Close();

        // Finally Quit the Application
        ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application)excel).Quit();
```

Comment: @RavitejaChekuri Chekuri : If you get the answer mark it as correct